# PHP displays a code in browser rather then execute but only for virtual hosts

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-13.10

I have installed fresh LAMP on Ubuntu 13.10 After installation PHP works fine if i put the PHP code to default localhost web folder /var/www

I created the virtual host. I did it as usually before and never had problems
I added the file to /etc/apache2/mods-enabled and activated

but then when i enter this virtual host in browser i can see the code of my index.php file in the browser.

Also when i execute php code from command line i can see source of the code and it is not executed.

What can this be?

Comment: Misconfiguration of apache?

Did you execute "php index.php" and you saw the sourcecode? Has index.php start and end php tags?

Comment: When run from command line i also see the source code instead execution

Comment: Is the file starting with <?php and ending with ?> tags?

Comment: yes. starting with <? and ending with ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use <?php and ?> not short tags, or if you want really use that (their use is discouraged due to compatibility issues), ensure that php.ini configuration have:

```
short_open_tag=On
```

Comment: thanks! this was the reason. This option was always off by default. but in ubuntu 13.10 default LAMP installation it is off for some reason.